# Identity Server 4 - log out

Tags: entity-framework, authentication, identityserver4

I follow this example [on Github](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/8_EntityFrameworkStorage) about Identity Server 4 and Entity Framework.

Then I follow this [guide](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Getting-Started-with-IdentityServer-4#Entity-Framework-Core) to get user from database and it works. But there is a problem during logging out user in Identity Server (http://localhost:5000/account/logout). Particularly when I return in Homepage after log out (that works) the username appear in view.

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
        {
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">@name <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a asp-action="Logout" asp-controller="Account">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        }
```

Is it an error of the source code of the guide available [here](https://github.com/scottbrady91/IdentityServer4-Example)? Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you confirm that the user is authenticated: `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`?

Comment: Yes, @RuardvanElburg I confirm. The following code is: `await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();` and then `await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLogoutSuccessEvent(user.GetSubjectId(), user.GetName()));` but user is again authenticated when I go to the homepage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is old, but I hope it helps someone.

When logging out make sure your controller does not return an action result. The logout should just be like this in your controller:

```
 public async Task Logout()
        {
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Cookies");
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("oidc");
        }
```

The callback in your identity server should redirect you back to the site.